# Display multiple IP address values for one system in a single row

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I cannot for the life of me get the systems with multiple IPs to display under one row. Below is the current SQL statement I have. systems with more than one IP show up as duplicated on the report.

```
SELECT SYS.Netbios_Name0 AS [Computer Name], 
       SYS.User_Name0 AS [Last Login User], 
       SYS.User_Domain0 AS [User Domain], 
       Sys.Resource_Domain_OR_Workgr0 AS [System Domain],  
       v_GS_Computer_System. Manufacturer0 AS [Manufacturer Name],  
       v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Model0 AS [Model Name],  
       v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.SystemType0 AS [System Type],  
       v_GS_PC_BIOS.SMBIOSBIOSVersion0 AS [Bios Version],  
       v_GS_PC_BIOS.SerialNumber0 AS [Service Tag],  
       v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.NumberOfProcessors0 AS [Active Processors],  
       v_RA_System_IPAddresses.IP_Addresses0 AS [IP Addresses]

FROM v_R_SYSTEM SYS
LEFT JOIN  v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM on SYS.ResourceID = v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceID 
LEFT JOIN v_GS_PC_BIOS on  SYS.ResourceID = v_GS_PC_BIOS.ResourceID
LEFT JOIN v_RA_System_IPAddresses on SYS.ResourceID = v_RA_System_IPAddresses.ResourceID
```

Comment: You probably want to provide some sample data and the desired output. Also try searching this site for "pivot".

Comment: Do you care if the IP addresses are in a single output column (say, comma-separated) or does each IP need to be in its own column, like IP1, IP2, IP3, etc.?

Comment: Comma separated is perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're okay with a single column showing the IP addresses as a comma-separated list:

```
SELECT SYS.Netbios_Name0 AS [Computer Name], 
       SYS.User_Name0 AS [Last Login User], 
       SYS.User_Domain0 AS [User Domain], 
       Sys.Resource_Domain_OR_Workgr0 AS [System Domain],  
       v_GS_Computer_System. Manufacturer0 AS [Manufacturer Name],  
       v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Model0 AS [Model Name],  
       v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.SystemType0 AS [System Type],  
       v_GS_PC_BIOS.SMBIOSBIOSVersion0 AS [Bios Version],  
       v_GS_PC_BIOS.SerialNumber0 AS [Service Tag],  
       v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.NumberOfProcessors0 AS [Active Processors],  
       [IP Addresses] = STUFF((SELECT ',' + rasi.IP_Addresses0
         FROM dbo.v_RA_System_IPAddresses AS rasi
         WHERE rasi.ResourceID = SYS.ResourceID
         FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value(N'.[1]',N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
FROM v_R_SYSTEM SYS
LEFT JOIN  v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM on SYS.ResourceID = v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceID 
LEFT JOIN v_GS_PC_BIOS on  SYS.ResourceID = v_GS_PC_BIOS.ResourceID;
```

*(If you're still getting duplicates here, it's because of the other joins, not the IP addresses.)*

If you need each IP address represented under its own column, you'll need to figure out the highest number of IP addresses that exist for any given system, and build a `PIVOT` statement using dynamic SQL. Not something I can invest in at 5:00 PM and when I don't even know you need it.